# Accuracy of rotational gates on IBM Quantum

Tags: quantum-gate, simulation

As a computer memory is finite, it seems reasonable to assume that a rotational angle of gates $Rx$, $Ry$ and $Rz$ (and $U1$, $U2$ and $U3$ gates as well) has some smallest step which can be distinguished (e.g. in change of an outcome probability distribution). I would also expect that on a simulator, the step is smaller than on a real quantum processor because the processors are still far from an ideal.

So, my question is what is the minimum step in the rotational angle which can be distinguished on IBM Quantum processors? Is the step on simulator smaller than on a real quantum processor?

Any reference do paper or link is appreciated.

Comment: The step on the simulator should be more precise than the real quantum processor. In the simulator, the error should be limited by the machine epsilon. For real quantum processor, I would imagine the noise is a huge role player there and thus the bound will depend on this. This is why these single rotation qubits gate are not implement this way on fault tolerance quantum computer but instead in sequence of $H$ and $T$. This way, the error is not depending on the noise of the system but the sequence itself.

Comment: In the 'qasm_simulator' it seems to be about 0.001 radians.

Comment: @Mauricio interesting. where did you get this number from? thanks.

Comment: @KAJ226 empirically. I just added a single Ry gate and plugged angles and a lot of shots to see when the measurements became indistinguishable from an empty circuit.